# Filter date from string with dates

Tags: php, regex, date

I have a string that has dates from a Google Calender JSON where I need to retrieve the dates in `YYY-MM-DD` format:

```
"content": {
    "$t": "When: Mon Jun 30, 2014 to Mon Jul 7, 2014 \n\u003cbr /\u003e\n\n\n\u003cbr /\u003eEvent Status: confirmed",
    "type": "html"
},
```

I thought about doing a function to "clean" using split, something like:

```
$string = "When: Mon Jun 30, 2014 to Mon Jul 7, 2014 \n\u003cbr /\u003e\n\n\n\u003cbr /\u003eEvent Status: confirmed";
$splitOne = split(' to ',$string);
$firstDate = split('When: ', $splitOne[0]);
$secondtDate = split(' \n', $splitOne[1]);
echo $firstDate[1]; echo '<br />';
echo $secondtDate[0]; echo '<br />';
```

But this echoes:

```
Mon Jun 30, 2014 // as expected
Mon Jul 7, 2014 \u003cbr /\u003e \u003cbr /\u003eEvent Status: confirmed // not expected, should be "Mon Jul 7, 2014"
```

What am I missing in the `split()`? And btw, is there a regex solution to this instead?

Comment: You should do a `var_dump($splitOne[1]);`, perhaps the character before the `\n` isn't a space. You could also explode on just `\n` and trim the result.

Comment: @jeroen, the var_dump gave `string(75) "Mon Jul 7, 2014 \u003cbr /\u003e \u003cbr /\u003eEvent Status: confirmed" `

Comment: There's no `\n` in there so nor your solution nor a solution that looks for `\n` is going to work...

Comment: @jeroen: exactly. Mystical for me... any idea why?  __http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s5v-kx8__

Comment: @jeroen, __[same result](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sx4-05h)__ with explode :/

Comment: It seems the double quotes you are using causes the `\n` to be converted to new-lines. I works with single quotes. Just do a `var_dump($string);` and you'll already see that the `\n`'s are gone.

Comment: @jeroen, that was weird and interesting! (wish that was a answer I could `+1`). Why does the double quotes behave different than single quotes? I tried with single quotes after your comment and it worked perfect.

Comment: It doesn't really solve the problem as I don't know where your input comes from. You should go for @AbraCadaver's solution instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier to just use a regex:

```
$string = "When: Mon Jun 30, 2014 to Mon Jul 7, 2014 \n\u003cbr /\u003e\n\n\n\u003cbr /\u003eEvent Status: confirmed";

preg_match('/When: (.*) to ([^\n]+)/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Then `trim()` `$matches` [1] and [2] if needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a regex solution. I threw up a regex for you [here](http://regex101.com/r/uW7oH2).

You can use the capture groups 1-6 to pull the info you need and convert it into the format you would desire.

the regex is:

```
(?:When:\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s([a-zA-Z]{3})\s(\d\d?)\,\s(\d{4})\sto\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s([a-zA-Z]{3})\s(\d\d?)\,\s(\d{4})).*
```

with capture groups:

```
\1 = Jun
\2 = 30
\3 = 2014
\4 = Jul
\5 = 7
\6 = 2014
```

PHP code example:

```
$re = '/(?:When:\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s([a-zA-Z]{3})\s(\d\d?)\,\s(\d{4})\sto\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s([a-zA-Z]{3})\s(\d\d?)\,\s(\d{4})).*/'; 
$str = 'When: Mon Jun 30, 2014 to Mon Jul 7, 2014 \n\u003cbr /\u003e\n\n\n\u003cbr /\u003eEvent Status: confirmed'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```